# Anonymous access icon not visible sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, anonymous-access, sharepoint-administration

I have a SharePoint 2010 site that I am trying to enable Anonymous Access on. However, the Anonymous Access icon in the Users and Permissions ribbon is missing so I am unable to complete the steps as listed in all of the other instructions.

Things I have tried:

1. Setting the `Enable Anonymous Access` checkbox in the Authentication Providers for my web application.
2. Setting my Anonymous Policy using all three permission policies.
3. Logging on as various members of my Administration group.
4. Restarting my website through IIS and then restarting my whole Windows Server.

Even though performing all the steps given above it is not showing me the Anonymous Access icon in the Site Permissions.

For clarity, I have followed all steps in the below web link until Step 8, where the Anonymous Access button is missing.

http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010

Any ideas how to do this?